# Next.JS - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

Seemingly out of nowhere, nothing was updated, this started happening -

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Identifier '_util' has already been declared (35:6)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const _store = require("../shared/store");
| const _api = require("../shared/util/api");
> const _util = require("../shared/util");
| const Home = ({ homeData  })=>{
|     const router = (0, _router.useRouter)();

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

I have two imports from two `util` folders in different locations, that's what it seems to complain about. But, worse yet, when I comment one of the imports, it started complaining about seemingly other random things.

I tried clearing `node_modules` and deleted `yarn.lock` and also ran `yarn cache clean` and it changed nothing. Updated all dependencies to their latest versions, reverted to exact versions from last known successful build - nothing. A bit of googling suggested I might've needed to change my `tsconfig.json` to export a more "browser friendly" ES version. Tried a few, no change. Tried a few other configuration changes, nothing. I even upgraded Node from 16 to 18, thinking... I don't know what I was thinking. I have no idea what's happening or why.

Distraught, I tried `yarn build`, everything seems fine. Pushed it to Vercel, it works great! But locally, with `yarn dev` this is still what I see. What could've happened on my local environment that would cause something like this? HELP!

Thank you!